# How to set landscape mode when i rotate Clock wise direction

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have app , When i rotate clockwise direction of iphone i need to display   my Report UIViewcontroller only landscape mode . Other UIViewcontroller is Portrait mode.

OtherUIviewController

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Report Uiviewcontroller

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{

     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```

But how to check it clock wise direction . Any sample//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for both `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` AND `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`. Otherwise you'll only have the screen rotated if the home button points to the right-hand side.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: this is not working , becuase i already tried this one. i need to clcok wise direction , and how to check in simulator . i am checking simulator in rotate right. this is right way. anyotherway

Comment: I think I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: only rotating  iphone simulator but not my view controller .    how to check in simulator in my view .

Comment: In Simulator you can use *Command + Left Arrow* and *Command + Right Arrow* to rotate the virtual device. There is also a menu item for that.